# How to determine Math Function domain?

Tags: qt, math

I'm writing a function graph plotting application with Qt. And I need an algorithm to determine the domain of the function.

here is the part were i draw the function graph

```
QPainterPath p(QPointF(-m_w/2,f(-m_w/2)));
m_painter->setPen(m_functionPen);
for(double x=-m_w/2, y; x<m_w/2; x++)
{
    y = f(x/100);
    p.lineTo(x,y*100);
}
m_painter->drawPath(p);
```

i think that if i find the domain i would stop the progrma from drawing out of it

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you give more detail to what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

Plotting software usually doesn't bother determining the domain; it just evaluates the function at every visible position and skips drawing any lines if the result was "undefined"/"NaN"/etc. Here is your code modified to do that skipping (untested, and I didn't match your brace style because I can't stand it):

```
QPainterPath p();
double previousY = 1/0 /* NaN */;
m_painter->setPen(m_functionPen);
for(double x=-m_w/2, y; x<m_w/2; x++) {
    y = f(x/100);
    if (y == y /* not-NaN test */) {
        if (previousY == previousY) {
            p.lineTo(x,y*100);
        } else {
            p.moveTo(x,y*100);
        }
    }
    previousY = y;
}
m_painter->drawPath(p);
```

(I'm assuming that `QPainterPath p()` will construct an empty path. I'm not familiar with the library you are using.) Note that this now treats the first point like the other points for simplicity of coding.

(Also, this strategy will not produce a correct graph if you are evaluating a function like `f(x) = 1/(x + 0.00005)`, because the undefined point will just be skipped over and you'll get a vertical line. There is no simple general solution for this problem.)

---

On the other hand, if you're trying to find reasonable bounds for your graph (your `m_w` variable), then determining the domain *is* the problem. In this case, it will depend on what kinds of functions you have and how they are represented.

Comment: Kevin is right. It's going to be difficult to calculate the domain, so just calculate your function for the visible domain

Comment: but we cant calculate in every possible value in R

Comment: I've updated my answer with code and the material I previously wrote in comments.